# JavaFx canvas mouse events

Tags: javafx

I would like to intercept mouse events on canvas only where I've drawn some shape, but in all other transparent area I would like to have behaviour like with property mouseTransparent true.
I can achieve that with ImageView, transparent areas doesn't intercept mouse events.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Drawing Operations Test");
    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #C9E3AF");
    root.setMinSize(1000, 1000);
    root.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        System.out.println("Clicked on root pane");
    });

    Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(512, 512);

    canvas1.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(Color.BLACK);
    canvas1.getGraphicsContext2D().fillRect(250, 250, 250, 250);
    canvas1.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        System.out.println("Clicked on canvas1");
    });
    canvas1.setPickOnBounds(false);

    Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas(512, 512);

    canvas2.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(Color.RED);
    canvas2.getGraphicsContext2D().fillRect(200, 200, 250, 250);
    canvas2.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        System.out.println("Clicked on canvas2");
    });
    canvas2.setPickOnBounds(false);


    SnapshotParameters param1 = new SnapshotParameters();

    param1.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    WritableImage image1 = canvas1.snapshot(param1, new WritableImage(512, 512));

    SnapshotParameters param2 = new SnapshotParameters();

    param2.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    WritableImage image2 = canvas2.snapshot(param2, new WritableImage(512, 512));

    ImageView view1 = new ImageView(image1);
    view1.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        System.out.println("Clicked on view1");
    });
    view1.setPickOnBounds(false);

    ImageView view2 = new ImageView(image2);
    view2.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        System.out.println("Clicked on view2");
    });
    view2.setPickOnBounds(false);

    // ImageView test
    // root.getChildren().addAll(view1, view2);

    // Canvas test
    root.getChildren().addAll(canvas1, canvas2);
    Scene sc = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(sc);
    primaryStage.setX(0);
    primaryStage.setY(0);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Is it even possible with Canvas?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned it is impossible to achieve using *Canvas*, but using *Group* and *Shape*s within gives you all the features of *Canvas* plus behaviour you expect.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ShapesApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Circle circle = new Circle(100);
        circle.setFill(Color.BLUE);

        Group group = new Group(circle);
        group.setOnMouseMoved(System.out::println);

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(group);
        stackPane.setPrefSize(400, 400);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(stackPane));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for respone.
I'm aware of Shape API, but I will have to draw/remove thousands of shapes in runtime.
Canvas seems to be most performant solution.
I'm still wondering how pickOnBounds works for Canvas, and why it's different than for images where transparent pixels doesn't intercept mouse events.

Comment: Why do you think that canvas is the most performant solution (in comparison to Group-Shapes)? Can you give any example to confirm that? I'm asking because I'm intrested in subcjet.

Comment: Mainly because of updates in scene graph.
Its much more expensive to add/remove 20 000+ Polylines(Shapes) every second to the scene graph than calling 20 000+ strokePolyline on graphicscontext

Comment: How exactly do you remove Polyline from Canvas GraphicsContext?

Comment: I'm just redrawing canvas with new polylines on it and that works fine